# Эффект затемнения css

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать такой эффект затемнения слайдера как [здесь](https://www.terem-pro.ru)

чтобы при скроллинге изменялся стиль opacity

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы он целиком находился здесь, а не ссылался на постороннюю страницу. Иначе ресурса может не стать и о чем вы спрашивали другим не будет понятно через год.

Comment: Я даже сейчас не особо понимаю вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так, посчитать максимально возможною прокрутку, а дальше по формуле `текущая_прозрачность = 1 - текущая_прокрутка\максимальная_прокрутка`

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const maxScrollTop = document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  div.style.opacity = 1 - window.pageYOffset/maxScrollTop;
});
```

```css
body{
  background: black;
  height: 2000px;
}
div{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://st4.depositphotos.com/1007248/22152/i/1600/depositphotos_221523808-stock-photo-various-chocolates-mint-leaves-small.jpg');
  background-size: cover; 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: а еще вопрос, а как организовать такой фон? чтобы можно было как слайдер поставить так и просто картинку?

Comment: @Ssasha `position: fixed`